# How do you (dynamically) justify cells to the right with CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a 2 col 2 row grid with 3 of the items/cells occupied.

I would like it to appear like:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
|  | C |

I know I can use `grid-column: 2;` on the 3rd item but that doesn't really help me if I have a dynamic number of rows and items.

I'm also aware of `direction: rtl;` on the wrapping element, but this obviously reverses the order which is not idea, eg:

| B | A |
| --- | --- |
|  | C |

I've tried `justify-content: right/end/flex-end` but no luck there either.

I am aware I can achieve the above with `flex-box` but was just curious if there was a way with CSS grid?

Comment: Could you show us some typical code, perhaps where there might be 3 columns on a wide device, 2 columns on a narrower one etc. I'm not clear how 'dynamic' you need the number of columns to be - how their width will be decided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have two columns you can write a specific selector and target the last item

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

/* place the last item at last column  */
.box div:last-child {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```